# Table can't be queried after change column position

Tags: hive

When querying table using "select * from t2p", the reponse is as blow. I think I have missed some concepts, please help me out.

> Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.objectinspector.LazyMapObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector

Step1, create table

```
create table t2p(id int, name string, score map<string,double>) 
partitioned by (class int)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '\\;'
map keys terminated by ':'
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile;
```

Step2, insert data like

```
1,zs,math:90.0;english:92.0
2,ls,chinese:89.0;math:80.0
3,xm,geo:87.0;math:80.0
4,lh,chinese:89.0;english:81.0
5,xw,physics:91v;english:81.0
```

Step3, add another column

```
alter table t2p add columns (school string);
```

Step4, change column's order

```
alter table t2p change school school string after name;
```

Step5, do query and get error as mentioned above.

```
select * from t2p;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an obvious error.
Your command `alter table t2p change school school string after name;` changes metadata only. If you are moving columns, the data must already match the new schema or you must change it to match by some other means.

Which means, the map column has to be matching to the new column. In other words, if you want to move column around, make sure new column and existing data types are same.

I did a simple experiment with int data type. It worked because data type are not hugely different but you can see metadata changed but data stayed same.

```
create table t2p(id int, name string, score int) 
partitioned by (class int)
stored as textfile;
insert into t2p partition(class=1) select 100,'dum', 199;
alter table t2p add columns (school string);
alter table t2p change school school string after name;
MSCK REPAIR TABLE t2p ;
select * from t2p;
```

You can see new column school is mapped to position 3( defined as INT).

[image: data]

Solution - You can do this but make sure new structure+data type is compatible to old structure.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  It works. However adding another map column item, it fails Why?

`create table t2p(id int, name string, score map<string,double>,school string) 
partitioned by (class int)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '\\;'
map keys terminated by ':'
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile;
Insert into t2p partition(class=2) select 3,"ww", map("math",94.0,"geo",60.5);
alter table t2p add columns (school string);
alter table t2p change school school string after name;
MSCK REPAIR TABLE t2p ;
select * from t2p;`